# Displaying an item from an array on page load

Tags: javascript, angular.js

This piece of Angular code is used to add/remove an item to a favourite array and display it on page load. Firstly I check if I have an array and then create one if not. It also checks the `localStorage` on page load.

How can this be improved?

```
$scope.favourites = $localStorage.favourites;

$scope.addExerciseToFavourites = function(exercise) {
  if($scope.favourites === undefined) {
    $scope.favourites = [];
    favouriteToggle(exercise)
  } else {
    favouriteToggle(exercise);
  };
};

function favouriteToggle(exercise) {
  if($scope.favourites.indexOf(exercise.exerciseName) == -1) {
      $scope.favourites.push(exercise.exerciseName);
  } else {
      $scope.favourites.splice($scope.favourites.indexOf(exercise.exerciseName),1);
  };
   $localStorage.favourites = $scope.favourites;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good start, but there are some improvements that can be made.

For instance, this chunk:

```
if($scope.favourites === undefined) {
  $scope.favourites = [];
  favouriteToggle(exercise)
} else {
  favouriteToggle(exercise);
};
```

Could be written as:

```
if($scope.favourites === undefined) {
  $scope.favourites = [];
}

favouriteToggle(exercise);
```

Since you always want to call the `favouriteToggle` function.

But you can go further, and treat `undefined` as simply another false'y value like `false`, `null`, empty string, and numeric zero:

```
if(!$scope.favourites) {
  $scope.favourites = [];
}
// ...
```

Which is synonymous with a common set-default-value-if-false'y idiom:

```
$scope.favourites = $scope.favourites || [];
// ...
```

You might also see it written as:

```
$scope.favourites || ($scope.favourites = []);
// ...
```

The three code blocks above are all equivalent: If `$scope.favourites` is false'y, set it to `[]`.

Since it's a simple one-liner, you can just move it out of the function entirely, and then just skip the entire function:

```
$scope.favourites = $localStorage.favourites || [];

function $scope.favouriteToggle(exercise) {
  if($scope.favourites.indexOf(exercise.exerciseName) == -1) {
      $scope.favourites.push(exercise.exerciseName);
  } else {
      $scope.favourites.splice($scope.favourites.indexOf(exercise.exerciseName),1);
  };
   $localStorage.favourites = $scope.favourites;
};
```

As for `favouriteToggle`, I'd name it `toggleFavourite` instead, just because it sounds more natural. But let's make it little more descriptive, and call it `toggleExerciseFavourite`.

Secondly, instead of finding the index twice with `indexOf`, it'd be easier to find it once, and store the result:

```
$scope.toggleExerciseFavourite = function(exercise) {
  var index = $scope.favourites.indexOf(exercise.exerciseName);

  if(index === -1) {
    $scope.favourites.push(exercise);
  } else {
    $scope.favourites.splice(index, 1);
  }

  $localStorage.favourites = $scope.favourites;
};
```

Lastly, I don't know Angular, I'm afraid, so I don't know how manipulating the `$localStorage` object works. But if `$scope.favourites` is just a reference to it, we can skip the last line, since we're manipulating the same object already:

```
$scope.toggleExerciseFavourite = function(exercise) {
  var index = $scope.favourites.indexOf(exercise.exerciseName);

  if(index === -1) {
    $scope.favourites.push(exercise);
  } else {
    $scope.favourites.splice(index, 1);
  }
};
```

Comment: Great Flambino, thank you very much for taking the time to do this for me. It is working great.

Answer (score 1):

@Flambino has already mentioned most things. Here are some additions and an alternative solution:

1. **Generals**

   Besides I do not like excessive `$` - but that's a matter of taste.
   Your functions are actually doing *too* much. `addElement` does in fact not only *add* an element, it also *removes* it. This violates the Principle of the Least Astonishment. Then, you are initializing your favs inside this function, which has nothing to do with *toggling*. This violates clearly the Single Responsibility Principle: Do only "one" thing in a function. And at least, you are storing the result to `localStorage`. This would also be better done outside.
2. **The actual code**

   @Flambino already pointed out that your initialization could be simplified to `scope.favs=scope.favs||[];`.

   I do not know any AngularJS, so I boiled it down to this:

   ```
   function toggleExcercise(exercise){
       var f=scope.favs.filter(function(x){ return x!== exercise });
       if(f.length < scope.favs.length) {
           scope.favs=f;
       } else {
           scope.favs.push(exercise);
       }
   }
   ```

   This:

   ```
   var f=scope.favs.filter(function(x){ return x!== exercise });
   ```

   tries to filter out the exercise. For that, the array is run through *once*.

   If you are using `indexOf` and `splice` the array is run through *more than once* worst case. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nmv1zeq/) to play with.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time Thomas - it takes me some time to read that quite confusing for a amateur.

Comment: I am open for questions ;)

Comment: So I think its this line that is confusing:
`var f=scope.favs.filter(function(x){ return x!== exercise });` there is a lot going on within one line also not seen a function within a variable I don't think. And also using `x` which I don't see where that comes from? guess its just the shorthand I can't get my head around.

Comment: The function I've used is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter. It takes another function (which I defined anonymous inline ) as it's argument, which describes the filtering rule x!==exercise. X is in this case arbitrary. I chose it out of habit - like in maths f(x).

Comment: To translate it into natural language: take the array of favs, filter it with the rule (taking every x and compare it to not beeing exercise - if true return the element else skip). Or: filter everything beeing equal to exercise out.